# Google Chart data export

Tags: csv, charts, export, google-visualization

When using Google Charts there's a [Toolbar](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/toolbar) concept, but it seems to only work with Google Drive spreadsheets (through the 'datasource' parameter). Is there a similar functionality that will allow to export data when it's retrieved from a database in general?

I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11717387/export-google-chart) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11349024/export-my-google-chart-table-data-to-excel-or-csv), but they are inconclusive.

Comment: Have you tried setting up a URL that points to somewhere on your own server and returns the data in CSV or whatever format? You could start with a simple example and go from there.

Comment: Yes, that's they way we're doing it now but we loose the filters applied through Google's Charts Dashboards. We would like to be able to serve the data after those filters have been applied.